# Three.js object self shadow itself depending on geometry

Tags: three.js, shader, shadow

I have playing a little with clara.io and i want to reproduce an image done with it.

[image: realistic]

I have searched the web for days looking up to reproduce what they call "Realistic" rendering.
As you can see on the image the six round part have they own shadows on the (one piece) brick from multiple lights sources.

I have no idea how they done that, if it is a simple setup, or a complex shader.
the best i can do is [that](http://jacquespugin.ch/tst/mrdoob-three2/test3.html) and i have no idea how to proceed to make and object shadowing itself depending of it's geometry.

any trails ?

Comment: I think that your best option is to have the round pegs as different objects from the main brick

Comment: Thanks, i have thought of that but before going that way I wanted to ask the community, if the Relistic rendering whas a simple setting which i didn't understand because i'm becoming stupid with age :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ie. Actually it is a very simple setup. The [THREE.Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) has two attributes `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` You can achieve the effect you are looking for (ie. self-shadowing) by setting both to `true`

Comment: unfortunately not, castShadow is only to castSadow of this object to another(s) object. And it's the same for receiveShadow, can only receive shadow from another object.

Comment: actually yes. take a look at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3uLuq/ demonstrating both shadowing a plane but also self-shadowing.

Comment: Yes, i know it's working on native THREE.js object. It's work with extruded text too, but can't make it works with an imported mesh. i have put castShadow on every light, and receiveShadow on the brick, nothing works, i have set the renderer too.

Comment: OK, can you create a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem. I am sure self-shadowing works on a Mesh also so your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: i have created a jsfiddle but it's not working because external link loading (model, texture) you can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TGmXZ/) if you want to see the same code working on a web server [click here](http://jacquespugin.ch/tst/mrdoob-three2/test3.html) thanks :)

Comment: hi, did you have time to take a look on the code. Thanks

Comment: I did look at the code and I saw you are doing environment mapping. So the question is if both are supported; environment mapping with shadows. If you take out of your code the environment mapping part I think you will see self-shadowing. So then it would be up to three.js to support it or not.

Comment: i try without the environment mapping same problem... i will try again to contact clara.io to try to see more clearly were the problem come. Maybe they use a special shader.....

Comment: hi, i contact clara.io and the answers was clara.io is not saving shadowMap because the three.js format don't support it. I know about setting lights and camera ShadowMap, but i know nothing about setting shadowMaps for a material, is it like envMap with a cubeMapping or is it something else ? can't find reference about this... :(

Comment: You don't have to do anything with the shadowmaps. three.js takes care of that part. Take a look at the jsfiddle I posted above.

Comment: So what was the answer here?

Comment: Hi, Thanks, your code example was effective. I had to push the résolution of the shadow maps to see something in fact, it was working previously, but almost invisible. I have a sort of noise effect on the shadows, maybe i should try not soft shadows but normal shadows. Thanks anyway for the help, i couldn't do it without you, and i appreciate greatly, the help you gave me.

Answer (score 5):

actually you need:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
light.castShadow = true;
object.castShadow = true;
object.receiveShadow = true;
```

i know its a little counter-intuitive that both the light and the mesh have the same attribute "castShadow", but that's how it works.

also remember to check the near, far, and size of the shadow camera of your **light** if the shadow doesn't appear or appears incorrectly.

here is an example i made:
http://shahar.thenachts.com/threejs/examples/selfShadow.html

it takes some time to load the model (the model is the floor and walls) and it's textures, so be patient.

to see the code, right click anywhere and choose "inspect element".